# Python - Hashlib decode

Tags: python, sqlite, hashlib

My app successfully can store the password in sqlite with hashlib.md5 encryption, but I do have a problem when I want to compare the input with the hash. Any help is appreciated!

```
    def chkPass(self):

    pas = self.password_entry.get()
    try:

        query = "SELECT system_password FROM 'system'"
        cur.execute(query,)
        records = cur.fetchone()
        print(records)
        if (hashlib.md5(pas.encode())) ==  records[0]:
            messagebox.showinfo('Login was Successful', 'Welcome')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'The password is incorrect, please try again')
        cur.close()
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'Fatal Error!', icon = 'warning')
```

UPDATE:
def chkPass(self):

```
    pas = self.password_entry.get()
    try:
        query = "SELECT system_password FROM 'system'"
        cur.execute(query,)
        records = cur.fetchone()
        print(records)
        if (hashlib.md5(pas.encode()).hexdigest()) ==  records[0]:
            messagebox.showinfo('Login was Successful', 'Welcome')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'The password is incorrect, please try again')
        print((hashlib.md5(pas.encode()).hexdigest()))
        cur.close()
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'Fatal Error! What the heck did you do?', icon = 'warning')
```

Now I have both pass and the encryption but I'm still getting error.Maybe the encryption and decryption are not same type?

SQLITE HASH -`('<sha256 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x000001E3E973C7F0>',)`
pass.input - `122f961db675f6a45b998594471a990b`

I don't have any experience with encription. In sqlite the pass is store like:`<sha256 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x000001E3E973C7F0>` is that ok?

Here is the code that writes pas into sqlite

```
    def NewPwd(self):
    pas = self.password_entry.get()
    password = hashlib.md5()
    password.update(pas.encode('utf-8').hexdigest())

    if password != '':
        try:
            query = "UPDATE 'system' SET system_password =?"
            cur.execute(query,(str(password), ))
            con.commit()
            print(password)
            messagebox.showinfo('Success!', 'The new password has been set!', icon = 'info')
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'Feilds are empty or password contains less than 5 characters', icon = 'warning')
```

Comment: What problem specifically?

Comment: We need `pas` and `record[0]`, and likely the code used to write the db to say. I think you want to save and later compare the `.digest()` or `.hexdigest()` of `hashlib.md5(pas.encode())` because the HASH object itself isn't going to compare. For instance `hashlib.md5(b"foobar") != hashlib.md5(b"foobar")` but their digests do.

Comment: For an example here on stackoverflow, you could get rid of the prompt, gui and db completely. Just assign a string such as `pas = "foobar"` and then try encrpyting and comparing to see what works. That would be good code to post here.

Comment: You now have the hexdigest in the verification step but you also need to fix the code that writes the db. You saved a string representation of the `HASH` object, not its hexdigest.

Comment: tdelaney I tried just on prompt but I'm getting two different values. <md5 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x0000025288121A50>
<md5 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x00000252881FD830>

Comment: Looking at `NewPwd` , what is `pas = self.password_entry.get()`? I assumed `pas` was going to be a string  but then `pas.encode('utf-8').hexdigest()` would fail because bytes objects don't have a `hexdigest` method.

Comment: You should do `hashlib.md5(pas.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()` both when saving and when verifying later.

Comment: pas = self.password_entry.get() is from the tkinter Entry. chkPass and newPwd are seperate tkinter windows. newPwd can reset master password, and chkPass is like app lockdown, if the pass from pas = self.password_entry.get() is matching sqlite password

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
    def chkPass(self):

    def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
        password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
        return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()

    pas = self.password_entry.get()
    print('Guess pass',pas)

    try:
        query = "SELECT system_password FROM 'system'"
        cur.execute(query,)
        records = cur.fetchone()
        old_pass = records[0]
        print('DB pass ', old_pass)

        if check_password(old_pass, pas):
            messagebox.showinfo('Login was Successful', 'Welcome')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'The password is incorrect, please try again')
        cur.close()
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'Fatal Error! What the heck did you do?', icon = 'warning')
```